# Can I use CLGeocoder apis in android in any possible way

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, clgeocoder

I want to use iOS CLGeocoder apis in android.Is there any possible way to do this because I dont want to use Google Maps geocoding apis?

PS:Downvoters,No question is stupid in this world.

Comment: Has your research shown any Apple iOS APIs accessible by non-Apple products?

Comment: I saw somehwere a guy has written a wrapper over clgeocoder for android but that is not working as they have stopped support.https://github.com/robovm/robovm/tree/master/cocoatouch/src/main/java/org/robovm/apple/corelocation

Comment: That particular project looks to be running Java on iOS - which would explain the wrapper. Have you considered licensing third party Map SDKs like https://developer.here.com/develop/mobile-sdks or https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/android-sdk/ which have Geocoder options

Comment: I have tried here maps they are serving my purpose.CLGeocode is best for me